# Copy worksheet from another workbook where the worksheet name can change depending on input

Tags: excel, vba

For work we have 1 excel workbook with many different sheets in, my role is to take the info from one of these worksheets at a time and put it into another workbook to work from. Pretty simple really, i'm currently learning VBA and am trying to automate this process to start.

This is what i have so far. It starts from a button press on the `"Macro Test Blank Sheet For new Data.xlsm"` workbook.

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Macro Test\2019-2020 Reflecto Record.xlsm"

 Workbooks("2019-2020 Reflecto Record.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:BA10000").Copy _
    Workbooks("Macro Test Blank Sheet For new Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

When finished the data has been copied and the `"2019-2020 Reflecto Record.xlsm"` workbook has been closed.

At the moment it is using `.Worksheet(1)` to use the first page in the Workbook to copy from. Is it possible for this to pick a worksheet by name where the name is entered into a cell next to the button to start the macro?

Comment: Rather than using a cell next to a button, you could also use an inputbox, or pick from a drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the name in cell A1 of a worksheet called "Sheet1" (just change the name to the worksheet where you're working)

Use this code:

```
Dim sourceSheetName as String

sourceSheetName = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Workbooks.Open "C:\Macro Test\2019-2020 Reflecto Record.xlsm"

Workbooks("2019-2020 Reflecto Record.xlsm").Worksheets(sourceSheetName).Range("A1:BA10000").Copy _
        Workbooks("Macro Test Blank Sheet For new Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I also suggest that you look into [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d) to automate this kind of process

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, two suggested ways of generating the name:

```
Sub sheetopener()
Dim MySh As String 'Dim MySh as a variable to hold the name of your sheet.

MySh = InputBox("Which sheet?", "Sheet picker") 'Set the name of your sheet with a popup box.
'Mysh = Thisworkbook.Sheet1.Range("A2").value 'Alternative set the name of your sheet in reference to a cell.

Workbooks("Name here").Sheets(MySh).Activate 'Activate the sheet with the just generated name.

End Sub
```